Could the etymology of rook be derived from the city Uruk?
The name "rook" in chess was derived from the Persian rukh. Could this possibly have come from the name of the ancient city Uruk?

As a new user you may not realize this but our ...er.. history here with questions that contain statements starting with "It is well known ..." is less than stellar. The mere appearance of that one statement is quite likely to cause a question downvotes. I've fixed it, but for future reference I'd highly suggest avoiding that trigger phrase, and instead linking to a reasonably reliable source actually saying that. If it is in fact "well known", it should be trivial to find one.

I am not sure this is the right community to ask this question. Nonetheless, you can find a discussion on the ethimology in A history of chess by A.J. Murray, 1913.
Excerpt from pages 160-161:

Rukh is less simple. The European dictionary statements that the word
means ' an elephant bearing a tower on its back ', or 'a camel ', are
based upon guesses suggested by the modern carved Parsi pieces, and
have no Persian authority whatever behind them. The guess of Herbelot
that rukh meant ' hero ' iu Middle Persian has been shown to depend
upon the use of the word rukh in the chapterheading of the legend of
the Eleven Champions, which has been added by some later copyists of
the Shahnama. It is true that Firdawst does describe the Rukh as a
champion or hero, reflecting the role that the chariot rider has
always played in the Indian epics, just as in Homer. But it is
necessary to show that Firdawsl or other early Persian writers used
rukh where one would naturally expect mubdriz (hero), and this has not
been done.
The word has two other well-established senses iu Persian, (1) the
cheek, and (2) the fabulous bird, familiar to readers of the Arabian
Nights. Its derivation in both these senses is unknown.3 There can be
no doubt that the chess-term Rukh meant simply chariot. The regular
practice in the westward march of chess has been this: the term the
meaning of which was well known to all who used it was translated into
the newlanguage and thus was replaced by a native and intelligible
word ; the term the meaning of which had ceased to be familiar to
those who were using it in the land whence chess was travelling was
adopted unchanged or in a native dress. Rat-ha can never have been
unintelligible in Sanskrit chess circles, and the analogy of the rule
followed in the case of every other of the chessmen requires that the
Persians translated rat ha also by some Persian word meaning chariot.
Although rukh has never been the ordinary word in use for chariot in
Persian, there is some evidence to show that it did bear that meaning
both in Persian and Arabic. In Vullers' Persian Lexicon, Bonn,
1855-64, s.v. shatranj (chess), p. 410, a native Persian dictionary is
quoted as giving 'araba as an alternative name for the rukh. 'Araba is
the ordinary Arabic word for chariot, which, like so many other Arabic
words, has been adopted as Persian. This makes the authority somewhat
late, and accordingly evidences the persistence of this knowledge of
the real meaning of rukh in Persia. The knowledge was, of course, by
no means general. For Arabic we have two valuable entries in early
Arabic-Latin glossaries, the knowledge of which we owe to Dozy. The
earlier of these is the Leyden Glossarium MS. 231 from the Leg.
Scaliger, the MS. of which is dated 12th c. by palaeographists. Here
we have currus, rukhkh ; * quadriga rukhkh dhu arba'a 'aflak (rook of
four wheels) ; and auriga, rukhkh, thumma sani* ar-rukhkli (rook, then
chariot- maker). In the other glossary, the Vocabulista, a Florence
MS. of which has been edited by Schiaparelli (Florence, 1871) we have,
p. 106, rukhkh, currus; and, p. 329, currus, 'ajala, —rukhkh, to which
a marginal gloss adds roc de seas. It seems quite clear from these two
entries in Spanish glossaries that the word rukhkh was in common use
among the Moors in Spain in the sense of chariot. There is also the
evidence of the chess-pieces in the Bibl. Nat. at Paris, which are
popularly known as Charlemagne's chessmen, in which the Rook is carved
as a two-wheeled chariot with a single man in it. Also a 15-16 c.
Hebrew MS. (Vatican, 171, f 2), which contains a poem on chess (v. d.
Linde, i. 180, text, 189), substitutes the chariot for the rook. There
is a possible reference in a Latin poem on chess (MS. Einsidlensis,
365) which is probably older than 1100 (11. 141-2): Extremos retinet
fines inuectus uterque Bigis seu rochus, marchio siue magis. Piyadah,
older payddah, which was Arabicized as baidaq, is a derivative of the
Persian pai, ' a foot ', and means a foot-soldier.


Ironicly (given the comment I added to the question), the phrase in the quoted text starting with "there can be no doubt that" sticks out like a sore thumb. I did a quick search on the term, and the first scholarly paper I dug up does in fact cast considerable doubt on that exact subject. This is of course a criticism of the author of the quote, not the author of this post. It seems quite possible that the tie between the two was a western invention (if you count Moorish Spain as "western"), not Persian in origin.

@T.E.D. thanks for your comment and answer, I can laugh with you at the irony of the "no doubt". I wanted to provide at least a starting point to the discussion, the book I mentioned is an interesting one ... but it is from 1913 and some new insights may have been obtained in the past 110 years.

The paper goes into pretty good detail about the Persian dictionary entry mentioned in the quote. "Most likely, the author wants to point out that the piece nowadays (i.e. in 1768) corresponding to the chariot, the araba, of the Indian chess game is the rukh.". To be fair, I think that paper is likely a "mere" 25 years old. :-)

@T.E.D. I am not familiar with etymology and linguistcs and I am a bit confused with all the dates :) ... maybe the Persian poem from 1100 AD is an early example of citogenesis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_citogenesis_incidents ) . Thanks again, interesting reading

Anything's remotely possible, but I'd say that's not reasonably likely at all. More the to point, there's absolutely no evidence supporting that idea. Evidence is the building material we make history out of. When we pile up what little of that building material we have, it just doesn't take a shape that gives that idea any support.
Similar pronunciation all by itself isn't very good evidence. Nearly every language is going to have words similar to "rook". For instance, English has "rock" in three completely different senses with different etymologies. That of course isn't evidence that ancient Persians were into guitar music (300 nonwithstanding), nor does it mean we should replace the castle piece with small stones.
So what do we know? Right now, there isn't any real consensus on the etymology of that Persian term, as applied to Chess. According to a survey of the sources done by Dr. Remke Kruk, a (now retired) Arabic scholar formerly of the university of Leiden, the major extant theories are:

Cryptid - There appears to have been an ancient Persian mythological creature by the name of rukh. What accounts we have of it greatly differ in what it looks like. None of these sources tie it to the game. They do share the exact name from the same language and era though.

Chariot - There aren't actually good ancient references that "ruhk" was a Persian word for chariot. In fact, that word in Persian appears to have been "arâba". The relation between ruhk and chariots is unknown in ancient sources until the 9th century, and first appears in Moorish Spain (from whence the game itself spread to Christian Europe). Its also true that chess' predecessor game Chaturanga we are reasonably certain contained chariots1.

Roc - There is some support during the Middle Ages associating the piece with the mythical giant bird. This particular cryptid appears to be of Arabic origin, not Persian, so it seems likely coincidental based on their similar-sounding names.

Camels and Castles - Medieval Islam frowned upon representational art of living things. Once the Persian game was adopted in the Arab world, this prohibition was quickly enforced upon chess. This caused the original gameset representations (using chariots in Spain at least) to become forgotten. When it was allowed again, Arab sets tended to use camels, while Europeans (not having that creature as a military unit) preferred the castle.



1 - The Sanscrit word for chariot was ratha. I guess it does start with the same consonant as "ruhk", but seems otherwise rather different to my somewhat untrained ear. It seems much closer to the araba that the (closely related) Persians reportedly actually used for "chariot"

A chess-head at work pointed out to me that the Indian predecessor game to Chess had chariots, so I've added that info. Still, while that strongly implies the piece was indeed originally meant to be a chariot, it doesn't really tell us where the weird name came from.
